# JavaScript, get dynamically created label's id

Tags: javascript, dynamic

The label that is beings created holds a guid that I need later.  I need to grab that information after the list of labels are created.  Here's my code:

```
        <button onclick="getAllListings()">Get All Listings Information</button>
    <br />
    <div id="divDataInsert" name="divDataInsert">
        @foreach (MVCTest1.Models.Listing foundListings in Model._listings)
        {
            string pk_listing_id = "listingsid_" + foundListings.PK_Listings_ID;
            string addressPK = "address_" + foundListings.PK_Listings_ID;
            string address = foundListings.Address.ToString();
            string cityPK = "city_" + foundListings.PK_Listings_ID;
            string city = foundListings.City.ToString();
            string statePK = "state_" + foundListings.PK_Listings_ID;
            string state = foundListings.State.ToString();
            string zipcodePK = "zipcode_" + foundListings.PK_Listings_ID;
            string zipcode = foundListings.ZipCode.ToString();
            string fullAddress = address + ", " + city + " " + state;

            if (foundListings.PK_Listings_ID != null)
            {
                <input type="text" id="lblListing_@pk_listing_id" value="@pk_listing_id" />
            }
        }
    </div>

    function getAllListings(){
    //var listingArray = [document.getElementById("lblListing_")];

    for (var i = 0; i < [document.getElementById("lblListing_")].length; i++) {
        var listingString = document.getElementById("lblListing_").value;
        var guid = listingString.split("_");
        alert(guid[1]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

My code behind

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string sql = "SELECT TOP 10 [PK_Listings_ID], [Address], [City], [State], [ZipCode] FROM dbo.Listings";
        ListingCollection ListOfListings = new ListingCollection();
        ListOfListings._listings = new List<Listing>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MVCInsertData"].ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;

                using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Listing listing = new Listing();
                            listing.PK_Listings_ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["PK_Listings_ID"]);
                            listing.Address = reader["Address"].ToString();
                            listing.City = reader["City"].ToString();
                            listing.State = reader["State"].ToString();
                            listing.ZipCode = reader["ZipCode"].ToString();

                            ListOfListings._listings.Add(listing);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        return View(ListOfListings);
    }
```

one of the answers involved adding a JS array in the code behind.  How do you do that?

*****Update*****

I have changed my input to this:

```
<input type="text" class="lblListing_" value="@pk_listing_id" />
```

And I have adjusted my JS to this:

```
    function getAllListings(){
    var listingsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("lblListing_");

    for (var i = 0; i < listingsArray.length; i++) {
        var listingString = listingsArray.value;
        var guid = listingString.split("_");
        alert(guid[1]);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, my JS is NOT inside a document.ready().  Should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to have your code behind emit a JavaScript array of all labels. A different--and this is the approach I would take--would be to use a class name as a "tag". Emit:

```
<input type="text" class="lblListing_" ...>
```

Then in your fixed (not dynamic) JavaScript, you can do:

```
function getAllListings(){
    var listings = document.getElementsByClassName("lblListing_");
    for (var i = 0; i < listings.length; i++) {
        var listingString = listings[i].value;
        var guid = listingString.split("_");
        alert(guid[1]);
    }
}
```

**Update for the follow-on question:**
The JavaScript can be placed anywhere but will not run on load. When and how to run the function depends on what you need it to do. (I assume the `alert` is just to test the logic.)

Comment: so, change my id to class and call the classname instead?  correct?

Comment: i'll add my code behind, but how do you create a JS array for all labels?

Comment: If you need the values in a submitted form, then you will still need the `id`s as well. If you switch to classes, you do not need a JS array. Otherwise, you can do something like build a C# array of label IDs (`"\"lblListing_" + pk_listing_id + "\""`), then join them into a single comma-delimited string, and emit that. My Razor experience is weak so I cannot be more specific there.

Comment: i have changed my input `<input type="text" class="lblListing_@pk_listing_id" value="@pk_listing_id" />`
and I've changed my JS:
`var listingsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("lblListing_");

        for (var i = 0; i < listingsArray.length; i++) {
            var listingString = listingsArray.value;
            var guid = listingString.split("_");
            alert(guid[1]);
            i++;
        }`
Not working.  I'm guessing I'm missing something

Comment: The class should be the same for all items: `lblListing` works. My sample code was not abbreviated when it excluded the listing ID from the class name. The actual GUID comes from the field value, so the class name need not be unique (unlike IDs in the HTML DOM).

Comment: if i'm understanding clearly `class="lblListing_"' is what it needs to be

Comment: The name itself is not important as long as (1) it is a constant and not variable and (2) the name in `class="xxx"` and `getElementsByClassName("xxx")` are the same.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  I have changed id to class="lblListing_" and my getElementsByClassName("lblListing_") to no avail.

Comment: i have updated my question if you are more of a visual person

Comment: I think I see my issue.  While I'm inspecting element in Chrome, I'm not grabbing the first column of the array to spit out that information.  I'm pretty sure you're right, but for some reason, I can't get that first column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83145/discussion-between-docmax-and-kevin-fischer).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that with jQuery

```
$('someSelector').each(function() {
    // do something
});
```

```js
$("input[id^='lblListing_']").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val().split("_")[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="lblListing_g-u-i-d-1" value="value1_g-u-i-d-1" />
<input type="text" id="lblListing_g-u-i-d-2" value="value2_g-u-i-d-2" />
```

Comment: I can only use JavaScript per my boss.